# Column automatically increasing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am setting a formula via my script such as this:

```
sheet.getRange("I1").setFormula("=CONCATENATE(\"CHECKED IN: \", SUM(I2:I))");
```

When I look at the field, I see the following: `=CONCATENATE("CHECKED IN: ", SUM(I2:I))`

Then somebody registers via my google form and I look at the value, it becomes this: `=CONCATENATE("CHECKED IN: ", SUM(I3:I))`

Basically, 2 became a 3. I assume this is because a new row was added to the sheet, however, my question is how can I prevent this? I want to count the sum in all the rows in that column without my formula getting adjusted by the spreadsheet.

Note: If I go and change 3 back to a 2 and then register again then it works. However, I would like to eliminate this manual step altogether.

EDIT:

To replicate follow these steps:

1. Create a new google form
2. Select Destination to a spreadsheet
3. Create a new Script from the Form.
4. Create the following script

Script Code:

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId()); 
form.deleteAllResponses();
form.removeDestination();
form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

//Code below is to resolve some bugs I've seen happen that prevented people from using the signup for the second time after I would reset it.
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId());
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.getRange(CHECKIN_COLUMN).setFormula("=CONCATENATE(\"CHECKED IN: \", SUM(I:I))");
sheet.getRange(VERIFIED_COLUMN).setFormula("=CONCATENATE(\"CHECKED IN: \", SUM(J:J))");
form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
```

5. Run the above code
6. Go look at the value of column I and J
7. Register through the form
8. Look at the value again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fix the range then add **$** to your formula.

```
sheet.getRange(CHECKIN_COLUMN).setFormula("=CONCATENATE(\"CHECKED IN: \", SUM($I$2:I))");
```

**Edit 2: To remove circular dependency**

On the top menu of a google spreadsheet do the following:

File > Spreadsheet settings

Choose the "Calculation" tab, and change "Iterative calculation" to ON.

Also choose the entire range **I:I**

```
sheet.getRange(CHECKIN_COLUMN).setFormula("=CONCATENATE(\"CHECKED IN: \", SUM(I:I))");
```

Comment: I already tried that and it does not solve the problem, unfortunately. The weird thing is that if I go back and I update 3 to a 2 then it works fine.

Comment: won't this work `sheet.getRange(CHECKIN_COLUMN).setFormula("=CONCATENATE(\"CHECKED IN: \", SUM(I:I))");` ?

Comment: I removed CHECKIN_COLUMN to eliminate confusion

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue, but after using $ the range remains fixed. can you share the copy of form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149947/discussion-between-ritz-and-bojan).